# How to configure database mail in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

when I configure the database mail it is showing the following error, what it means ?

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the error is self-explanatory: only sysadmins can configure database mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have the required permission to access the database mail settings. Ask your DBA to configure it for you. If you don't have a DBA then you will need to logon to the server with an account that has sysadmin server role.